# Show that the following linear map is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space with inner product $\langle -, - \rangle$, and let $U$ be an $m$-dimensional subspace of $V$. Suppose $u_1, \dots, u_m$ is a basis for $U$. Define $T:V \to \Bbb R^{m}$ by $T(v) = (x_1, \dots, x_m)$ where $x_i = \langle v, u_{i} \rangle $ for $i=1, \dots, m$. Show that $T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $T|_U\colon U \to \Bbb R^m$ is an isomorphism (this implies that the full map is surjective). But since $\dim U = m$, we can show that $T|_U$ is injective instead (thus it is an isomorphism by dimension reasons). This, in turn, is obvious from $(u_1,\ldots, u_m)$ being a basis for $U$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ being [non-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondegenerate_form).